# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.83 MiB for an array with shape (5004, 96) and data type int32

Tags: python, dataframe, out-of-memory, spacy

When I want to process a huge csv file I'm getting a MemoryError `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.83 MiB for an array with shape (5004, 96) and data type int32`. The error happens at:

```py
processed_texts = [text for text in nlp.pipe(str(tokenized_texts),
                                             disable=["ner",
                                                      "parser"])]
```

Will this be fixed when I'm using multiple threads? If so, has anybody some examples in Python, because I'm coming from Java..

Whole script:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('posts_result.csv')
df_sample = df.sample(frac=0.1, replace=False, random_state=1)

""" DATA EXPLORATION """

text_test = df_sample.post.tolist()


# Start the tokenization
def tokenize_hashtag(text):
    punctuations = '!"$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?[\\]^_`{|}~'
    for punctuation in punctuations:
        text = str(text).replace(punctuation, '')
    text = text.lower()
    text = text.split()
    return text


tokenized_texts = [tokenize_hashtag(text) for text in text_test]

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

processed_texts = [text for text in nlp.pipe(str(tokenized_texts),
                                             disable=["ner",
                                                      "parser"])]

df_sample['processed'] = tokenized_texts

tokenized_texts = [[word.text for word in text if (word.pos_ == 'NOUN' or word.pos_ == 'VERB' or word.pos_ == 'PROPN') and not len(word.text) >12 and not word.is_punct and not word.is_stop and not word.text=='X'
                   and not word.text == '@Name']
                    for text in processed_texts]
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.83 MiB for an array with shape (5004, 96) and data type int32 @Jimenemex

Comment: Are you sure that you have provided the whole program?  For example, are some import statements missing?  Also, how many lines is your input file and what does a typical line look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really provided enough information here, but it looks like you can't hold all the spaCy docs in memory.

A very simple workaround for this would be to split your CSV file up and process it one chunk at a time.

Another thing you can do, since it looks like you're just saving some words, is to avoid saving the docs by changing your for loop a bit.

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def keep_word(word):
    if word.pos_ not in ("NOUN", "VERB", "PROPN"):
        return False
    if word.text == "@Name":
        return False
    return True

out = []
for doc in nlp.pipe(str(tokenized_texts),disable=["ner", "parser"]):
    out.append([ww.text for ww in doc if keep_word(ww)])
```

This way you'll just keep the strings you want and not the docs, so it should reduce memory usage.

A couple of other comments about your code...

Whatever you're trying to do with the hashtag function it's not working. If you call `str(text.split())` the output is really weird - it'll turn `I like cheese` into `['I', 'like', 'cheese']` - and it will cause spaCy to give you nonsense output. I recommend just not using that function, spaCy expects to deal with puncutation.

You seem to be using spaCy to remove words based on part of speech (for the most part), but that's generally not a good idea - modern text processing doesn't need that kind of prefiltering. It was still common practice like 15 years ago but you should just be able to give whole sentences to any reasonable model, and they'll be better than overly filtered text.